# Where am I getting it wrong?

Tags: express

I want to implement a functionality that enables users to filter/get businesses by location. This is my logic:

1. Declare a variable to hold the filtered array
2. Loop through the businesses
3. If the query is not undefined
4. Call the filter method on the businesses
5. if the query is equal to the location available in the database
6. Push the businesses with the specified location(s) into the array
7. return a success message and status code with the businesses in the

specified location or an error message with the appropriate status code.

```
This is the mock database:
const businesses = [
  {
    id: 1,
    businessName: 'Kulikuli and Sons Limited',
    description: 'We take you to heaven and back',
    email: 'kososhi@gmail.com',
    location: 'Kaduna',
    category: 'Hospitality',
    phoneNumber: '07033288342'
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    businessName: 'Rochas Limited',
    description: 'We satisfy all your maintenance',
    email: 'rochas2u@gmail',
    location: 'Lagos',
    category: 'Repairs and Maintenance',
    phoneNumber: '07033288341'
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    businessName: 'Lekoto Travels',
    description: 'Travel with us and you won\'t regret it',
    email: 'lekotoboss@gmail.com',
    location: 'Kaduna',
    category: 'Travels and Tours',
    phoneNumber: '07033288344'
  },
];

This is the method to control the route: GET /businesses?location=<location>
static filterByLocation(req, res) {
    const filteredLocation = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < businesses.length; i += 1) {
      if (typeof req.query.location !== 'undefined') {
        businesses.filter((business) => {
          if (business.location === req.query.location) {
            filteredLocation.push(business);
          }
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'Success',
        location: filteredLocation
      });
    }
    return res.status(404).send({
      status: 'Fail',
      message: 'Location not found'
    });
  }
However, the code isn't working as expected. Where am I getting it wrong?
```

Comment: Mine eventually worked, I was testing it wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, Filter function return filtered result not need to push in array based on condition, and res.send does not return JSON so you have to use res.json() or res.send(JSON.stringify(json)). You are returning response from inside for loop that will not work.

```
static filterByLocation(req, res) {
    const filteredLocation = businesses.filter((business) => {
        return business.location === req.query.location;
    });
    if (filteredLocation.length !== 0)
        return res.status(200).json({
            status: 'Success',
            location: filteredLocation
        });
    return res.status(404).json({
        status: 'Fail',
        message: 'Location not found'
    });
}
```